# How to add music upload functionality to rails website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In short: I'd like to provide users with the ability to upload songs to the website. I'd like this functionality to correspond with the database.

E.g it'll have an artist, and song model.

An Artist has many songs, and a song belongs to an artist.

How/can this be achieved in rails?

What code will I need to implement for the upload song file functionality. And how can I have these uploads be logged and connected to the database?

I've tried paper clip but i'd like to do this without a gem if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Try PaperClip -> https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: "I'd like to do this without a gem if possible." Don't.

Comment: Agree with @meager.  [Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) is an alternative to PaperClip. Both are good

Comment: Gotcha--perhaps ill explore more gems and give paper clip another shot. My first attempt was very brief. I figured if I build the functionality ill understand how it works better. However, why invent the wheel I suppose!

Comment: Hey look, a list of file upload gems: http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads